# Query based on field prompts for parameter requirement

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

I'm creating a form where user enters client data on various fields (tbl_Clients). This table is connected with others like (tbl_ClientContacts).

What I'm trying to do is to list personal contact information (name, phone, email, position) in a list box from table (tbl_ClientContacts) inside a form responsible for entering client data and later on using those contacts on reports as well BUT

Everytime when I open this form I'm being prompted with param required box.

on a query responsible for those contact data im using following code (end of select clause):

```
  WHERE (((Tbl_Client.ClientName)=[Forms]![Frm_Client]![ClientName]))
```

I'm trying to recover this data based on field in form. It can't be done with requery connected to a button as well.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Are you sure we speak about Excel here and not Access? If it is Excel and you speak about tables do you mean ListObjects? Can you clarify and give a bit more background information?

Comment: Of course we are :( im dumb hehe. editing now.

Comment: The whole purpose of this project is to create simple CRM system for our small team. people were using excel and notepad kind of contact tracking until now. I'd like to have a form where i can edit basic customer data and show internal contacts from this customer. those contact are entered through separate form and this form should be ready available as a button in the main customer (client) form.

thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information to solve the problem but the error description suggests either  Access just doesn't understand the ClientName reference or you have ClientName's address wrong.  See http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm .  See next comment also

Comment: Those Form addresses are brittle as the address depends on where you are calling from.  Instead I prefer to make properties.  Access can detect public functions everywhere.  So add a code module with public GetClientName and SetClientName wrapping a private ClientNameString.  Then call SetClientName after you update it. 
 CallGetClientName in your query.  The problem should be much easier to resolve after that.